# Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm

I'm trying to insert `values` using mysql in nodejs. I had written the following code and installed MySQL support via npm,But canot to INSERT INTO the table due to this problem.

My code;

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var values=randomValueHex(8);

var sql = "INSERT INTO `activationkeys`(`activationKey`, `productId`) 
VALUES ( values ,'3')";
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("1 record inserted");
});
```

My Error on terminal:

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3')'

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: your SQL query is invalid. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: Do console.log(this.sql) before the error handling and see in your log what is the query being executed

Comment: `values` is a MySQL keyword. You probably want `sql = "... VALUES(" + values + ", '3')"` but you better use prepared statements. In its current status your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: and i always use `sequelize` for db handling in node: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/ - try it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using back quote for the column names? We do not need that in column names. You can simply create your dynamic sql query by using `+` operator on the column values like this:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO activationkeys (activationKey, productId) VALUES ( " + values + " ,'3')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO `activationkeys`(`activationKey`, `productId`) 
VALUES ( values ,'3')";
```

Please try this

```
 var sql = "INSERT INTO `activationkeys`(`activationKey`, `productId`) 
    VALUES ( " +  values + " ,'3')";
```

provided values is a string

Answer (score 0):

`values` currently means nothing the way you're using it in the SQL query.

What is `values`? Is it an integer, or a string?

Nevertheless, you need to concatenate the values variable within the string.

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO `activationkeys`(`activationKey`, `productId`) VALUES (" + values + ",'3')";
```

Comment: [*"Is it an integer?"* -- No! *"Is it a string?"* -- No!](https://youtu.be/eh8eb_ACLl8?t=1m22s) -- [**It is a keyword**!](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-V) ;-)

Comment: Why downvote? My answer is basically the same as the other ones, with more details. Enlighten me please. @axiac I meant the `values` JS variable, not the VALUES before the parenthesis.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I just liked your rhetorical questions and turned them into a funny comment (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

And one more correction `values` variable have to give like this `'" + values + "'` . This is the most correct way of define as a variables. Otherwise you give like this  `" + values + "` , you may be have an error accure like this `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'xxxxxx' in 'field list'`. And my code is

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO `activationkeys`(`activationKey`, `productId`) VALUES ( '" +  values + "' , 3 )";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple way to write SQL query in you JavaScript code.

Try It Once

const QUERY = INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName) VALUES ( "${firstName}", "${lastName}")

Note: Please wrap your complete query into the back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable `values`, but you forgot to concat with the query,
you can use the `Template literals` method.

```
var values=randomValueHex(8);
var sql = `INSERT INTO activationkeys(activationKey, productId) VALUES ( '${values}' ,'3')`;
    
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
});
```